# Azure Function App Microsoft Identity Provider authentication. Make OpenAPI/Swagger endpoints anonymous

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, openapi, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm using Azure Active Directory identity provider to secure my Azure Function App. This setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-tenant. I'm also using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi to render OpenAPI document and Swagger UI within my Azure Function App. My question is, how can I make these OpenAPI document and Swagger UI endpoint anonymous. ATM I need to authenticate to also access these endpoints.